# react-native-navigation showInAppNotification blank

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

Trying use this.props.navigator.showInAppNotification

```
this.props.navigator.showInAppNotification({
  screen: "example.InAppNotification", 
  passProps: {
    title: 'Title',
    body: 'Body...'
  }, 
  position: 'bottom',
  autoDismissTimerSec: 3
});
```

screen *InAppNotification* is registered, but see notification with blank content:
[image]

Can anyone help with this?

example.InAppNotification:

```
export default class InAppNotification extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {JSON.stringify(this.props)}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the content of. example.InAppNotification

Comment: add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try by adding `flex:1` to container `View`

```
export default class InAppNotification extends Component {
  render() {
  console.log(this.props);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>
        {JSON.stringify(this.props)}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

also you need to register InAppNotification screen correctly

Comment: nothing changed. Also i doesn't see the console.log in dev tools.

Comment: did you register InAppNotification screen?

Comment: ```Navigation.registerComponent('cabinetmobile.InAppNotification', () => WrongComponent, store, Provider);```
There was ```WrongComponent``` instead ```InAppNotification```.
Thanks for help!